# Close door after player has entered a room

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, game-mechanics, first-person-shooter

I can't figure out how to make the triggered door open and then close again. I managed to open the door, but can't figure how to close it again once the player is inside the room. Here's my code so far:

```
public GameObject upDoor;
public GameObject downDoor;
public bool openDoor;

void Update()
{
    if(openDoor) //(openDoor == true)
    {
        upDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
        downDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger Entered");
    openDoor = true;
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{

}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    openDoor = false;
}
```

---

This is how I edited the code, but I'm having a compile error.. I don't know what else I could do?

I tried else->return false; but that would cause an error as well.

```
void Update()
{
    if(openDoor) //(openDoor == true)
    {
        upDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
        downDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        upDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.down) * Time.deltaTime);
        downDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: "I'm having an error" should *always* be followed with *the full description of the error*. Don't make us guess. Here you have a mismatched parenthesis in this line: `upDoor.transform.Translate(Vector3.down) * Time.deltaTime);` - see how you have one `(` but two `)`s? Always make sure your parentheses occur in matched pairs.

Comment: Your last code seems okay, except, that you wrote an extra ) by accident, and you have to stop closing the door once it's fully closed. One way to do that is to count how many frames open it is, ++ when opening and -- when closing, don't close any more once it's 0.